# "SyntaxError: unexpected }" when setting up backbone.js with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, syntax-error

Ok, I'm baffled. I am trying to set up a rails/backbons SPA. I am following along with this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1?autoplay=true

I get this error from the browser when trying to access the root page:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Main#index

Showing /Users/Eamon/raffle/raffler/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6      raised:

SyntaxError: unexpected }
  (in /Users/Eamon/raffle/raffler/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/entry.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Raffler</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

Here is my code - I only got a few minutes into the video.

raffler.js.coffee

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers

window.Raffler =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
  init: -> 
    new Raffle.Routers.Entries()
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  Raffler.init()
```

entries_router.js.coffee

```
class Raffler.Routers.EntriesRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @entries = new Raffler.Collections.EntriesCollection()
    @entries.reset options.entries

  routes:
    "new"      : "newEntry"
    ''         : 'index'
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"

  newEntry: ->
    @view = new Raffler.Views.Entries.NewView(collection: @entries)
    $("#entries").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    alert "home page"

  show: (id) ->
    entry = @entries.get(id)

    @view = new Raffler.Views.Entries.ShowView(model: entry)
    $("#entries").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    entry = @entries.get(id)

    @view = new Raffler.Views.Entries.EditView(model: entry)
    $("#entries").html(@view.render().el)
```

I know most of the above code is irrelevant at this point in the cast...it was all created by the scaffold generator - I figured I didn't have to delete anything.

entry.js.coffee

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'entry'

  defaults:

class Raffler.Collections.EntriesCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Raffler.Models.Entry
  url: '/entries'
```

The above file is where I think the error is occurring. I just can't seem to find a syntax error anywhere. I noticed in the code that goes with the railscast on the cast page, that entry.js.coffee just has

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model
```

I tried deleting everything but that line for the entry.js.coffee file - when I go to the root page...it just says "Loading...," which is just a reflection of the code used as a placeholder for before the app initializes.

Maybe a fresh pair of eyes...

**UPDATE**

I found someone with a similar issue here:

[rails: backbone-on-rails gem-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059724/rails-backbone-on-rails-gem)

After seeing this and a few other related posts...I tried deleting the //=require_tree . line from application.js. A few other posts say it needs to be at the bottom...but mine already was, so that isn't the problem either. Incase it is relevant, here is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require backbone_rails_sync
//= require backbone_datalink
//= require backbone/raffler
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: yah...that was a typo in my post...it is properly indented in my code. I just edited the post to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Checking your *entry.js.coffee* code in "Try Coffeescript" on [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/), I get [the same error](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Raffler.Models.Entry%20extends%20Backbone.Model%0A%20%20paramRoot%3A%20%27entry%27%0A%0A%20%20defaults%3A%0A%0Aclass%20Raffler.Collections.EntriesCollection%20extends%20Backbone.Collection%0A%20%20model%3A%20Raffler.Models.Entry%0A%20%20url%3A%20%27%2Fentries%27).

Adding `{}` to `defaults:` cleared the error and now [renders correctly](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Raffler.Models.Entry%20extends%20Backbone.Model%0A%20%20paramRoot%3A%20%27entry%27%0A%0A%20%20defaults%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Raffler.Collections.EntriesCollection%20extends%20Backbone.Collection%0A%20%20model%3A%20Raffler.Models.Entry%0A%20%20url%3A%20%27%2Fentries%27).

*entry.js.coffee*

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'entry'

  defaults: {}

class Raffler.Collections.EntriesCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Raffler.Models.Entry
  url: '/entries'
```

Comment: it got rid of the error...but according to the railscast a popup should be displayed that says "home page". This doesn't happen. when i put your code in to "Try Coffescript" and hit "run" it tells me: ReferenceError: Raffler is not defined