# Backbone on Rails ExecJS::RuntimeError in Main#index

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm learning Backbone.js by going through the Backbone on Rails Railscast.  In part 2 episode 325 they add `$('#new_entry')[0].reset()` into the entries_index.js.coffee file (see below).  This is supposed to clear the text from the form once it has been added to the list.  I'm using Rails version 4.0.0.

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['entries/index']

  events:
    'submit #new_entry': 'createEntry' 

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(entry: @model))
    @collection.each(@appendEntry)
    this

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Raffler.Views.Entry(model: entry)
    @$('#entries').append(view.render().el)

  createEntry: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create name: $('#new_entry_name').val()
    $('#new_entry')[0].reset()
```

I get these errors when reloading the page on localhost:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Main#index
SyntaxError: unexpected CALL_START
  (in /Users/lionelramos/Documents/raffler/app/assets/javascripts/views/entries/entries_index.js.coffee)
```

My log has this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unexpected JS
  (in /Users/lionelramos/Documents/raffler/app/assets/javascripts/views/entries/entries_index.js.coffee)):
```

My index template (index.jst.eco) is minimal:

```
<h1>Raffler</h1>

<form id="new_entry">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="new_entry_name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<ul id="entries"></ul>
```

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617928/syntaxerror-unexpected-when-setting-up-backbone-js-with-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to say that this error had to do with the indentation on the event.preventDefault().  I had a couple of spaces and a tab instead of 2 tabs. Fun times!

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly adding parentheses around your method calls and/or curly brackets around object arguments as demonstrated in [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1615).

Specifically here:

```
@collection.create({ name: $('#new_entry_name').val() })
```

According to my test at [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org):

```
# this parses
action key: "value", variable

# while this doesn't
action key: "value", some_function()
```